# Listing all possible values for SOAP enumeration with Python SUDS

Tags: python, soap, enumeration, suds

I'm connecting with a SUDS client to a SOAP Server whose wsdl contains many enumerations like the following:

```
</simpleType>
  <simpleType name="FOOENUMERATION">
  <restriction base="xsd:string">
   <enumeration value="ALPHA"><!-- enum const = 0 -->
   <enumeration value="BETA"/><!-- enum const = 1 -->
   <enumeration value="GAMMA"/><!-- enum const = 2 -->
   <enumeration value="DELTA"/><!-- enum const = 3 -->
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

In my client I am receiving sequences which contain elements of these various enumeration types. My need is that given a member variable, I need to know all possible enumeration values. Basically I need a function which takes an instance of one of these enums and returns a list of strings which are all the possible values.

When I have an instance, running:

```
print type(foo.enumInstance)
```

I get:

```
<class 'suds.sax.text.Text'>
```

I'm not sure how to get the actual simpleType name from this, and then get the possible values from that short of parsing the WSDL myself.

**Edit:** I've discovered a way to get the enumerations given the simpleType name, as below, so my problem narrows down to findingthe type name for a given variable, given that type(x) returns suds.sax.text.Text instead of the real name

```
 for l in  client.factory.create('FOOENUMERATION'):
    print l[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a rather hacky way to pull this off, but hopefully someone still has a better answer for me. For some reason objects returned from the server have enums with the `suds.sax.text`.Text type, but those created with the factory have types related to the enum, so this works:

```
def printEnums(obj,field):
     a=client.factory.create(str(getattr(client.factory.create( str(obj.__class__).replace('suds.sudsobject.','')),field).__class__).replace('suds.sudsobject.',''))
     for i in a:
         print i[0]
```

Then I can do:

```
 printEnums(foo,'enumInstance')
```

and even if foo was returned from the server and not created by a factory get a listing of the possible values for foo.enumInstance, since I factory create a new class of the same type as the one passed in. Still, I can't imagine that this mess is the correct/best way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the **name** of the enum you want, you should be able to treat the enumeration object suds gives you like a dictionary, and do a direct lookup with that name. For example, if your enumeration type is called `SOAPIPMode` and you want the enum named `STATIC_MANUAL` in that enumeration:

```
soapIPMode = client.factory.create('SOAPIPMode')
staticManual = soapIPMode['STATIC_MANUAL']
```

The resulting value is of type `suds.sax.text.Text` which acts like a string.

You can also iterate over the enumeration type as if it were an array:

```
for i in range(len(soapIPMode):
    process(soapIPMode[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can feed in the WSDL into the `ElementTree` component on Python and use it to obtain the enumerations.